# How to specify values and names in bulk when creating a vector (or list)?

Tags: r

I know that one can do something like this

```
x <- c(foo = 1, bar = 4)
```

Suppose I want to create a vector whose values and names are to be obtained from expressions such as `the_values(some, args)` and `the_names(some, args)`?

I know that I can create the desired vector via *two* assignments:

```
x <- the_values(some, args)
names(x) <- the_names(some, args)
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with a single assignment?

I'm also interested in the analogous question for lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
x <- setNames(the_values(some, args), the_names(some, args))
```

For the first example

```
setNames(c(1,4), c("foo", "bar"))
```

It would work for both `list` and `vector`s

```
setNames(list(1,4), c("foo", "bar))
```

---

Another option is `names<-`

```
x <- `names<-`(the_values(some, args), the_names(some, args))
```